How do I get flutter to show the proper paste option for input fields
This is on a real device plugged into my mac. I have no idea what causes this issue. It periodically shows up and each time I do all kinds of things to get it corrected like 'flutter clean' and rebuilding my project and eventually it just goes away and I do not know why. When I long press to get the paste option to come up this weird looking square icon appears seen below. After selecting it, it opens another weird feature. Problem is I cannot paste now and this is a really annoying issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?
After long press:

Paste option nowhere to be found. Clicking on the weird icon causes the following:

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

This feature is specific to IOS. it is called "live text".
It appears upon double-tapping inside the textfield
It's controlled by the device's OS and not by Flutter.
You can dislabe it it within IOS settings:

Open Settings and tap General.
Tap Language & Region.
Turn off Live Text.


(Image credit)

You can disable it here:
Settings > General > Language & Region, disable Live Text at the bottom.
